# The input does not agree with the output tensor type

Tags: python, pytorch

The network model of yolov5 is modified, and the Focus layer in yolo is replaced by the ENet network, But we get this error:RuntimeError: Input type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.cuda.HalfTensor) should be the same., I do not know the reason?

The solution found on the Internet is to convert the input type to the GPU type.But the project files are too many, do not know where to add?
for example:

```
device = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

inputs = inputs.to(device)
```

The error starts when the parameter x is assigned to the parameter main.Is that not possible in python?

```
class Bottleneck(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, channels, internal_ratio=4, kernel_size=3, padding=0, dilation=1,
                 asymmetric=False, dropout_prob=0, bias=False, relu=True):
        super(Bottleneck, self).__init__()
        internal_channels=channels//internal_ratio

        self.ext_conv1=nn.Sequential(
                nn.Conv2d(channels,internal_channels,kernel_size=1,stride=1,bias=bias),
                nn.BatchNorm2d(internal_channels),
                activation())
        self.ext_conv2=nn.Sequential(
                    nn.Conv2d(internal_channels, internal_channels, kernel_size=kernel_size,
                            stride=1, padding=padding, dilation=dilation, bias=bias),
                    nn.BatchNorm2d(internal_channels),
                    activation())
        self.ext_conv3=nn.Sequential(
                nn.Conv2d(internal_channels,channels,kernel_size=1,stride=1,bias=bias),
                nn.BatchNorm2d(channels),
                activation())
        self.ext_regul=nn.Dropout2d(p=dropout_prob)
        self.out_activation=activation()
                
    def forward(self,x):
        main=x
        #print(type(x))
​        #print("==========")
​        ext=self.ext_conv1(x)
​        ext=self.ext_conv2(ext)
​        ext=self.ext_conv3(ext)
​        ext=self.ext_regul(ext)
​        out=main+ext
​        return self.out_activation(out)
```

Comment: This is a runtime type error which is fairly common in Python. All data has a type. In the case where you are trying to feed that data to some GPU library you'll need to make sure the data is sent in the format the library is expecting so that it can perform the operations it needs to perform.

Could you provide some more sample code?

Comment: OK, I've uploaded the code samples